# Cesium Plotting is not working for IOS App but Works for Android?

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, cesiumjs, cordova-ios

I am building an application where we are plotting trees using Cesium 3D Map. I tried to run the app on three different version of IOS 9, 10 and 11 but Cesium map doesn't load, it just shows the globe (only half of the screen) but doesn't plot. I am using Xcode 9.1 and also using apple's free trail developer account to deploy the app.

I am using IONIC Cordova frame work to Build the App.

I am using the exact same thing for Android and it works fine.

I added a picture of the app hopefully it will help.

Comment: Please add the code that you used, otherwise it is difficult to say which is the problem.

Comment: There are lots of code, i am not sure which one to upload? is there any specific one that you want to see ?